# How do I read data from a register on an FPGA board using PySerial?

Tags: serial-port, fpga, pyserial, uart, cpu-registers

I have implemented a simple lock in amplifier on an FPGA board, and I'm writing the detected amplitude to a register on the board. I'm then using a microprocessor to read from the register while the processor itself is connected to my laptop via UART. The address of the register is 4, and when I enter "r 0xf0000004" into CuteCom, it outputs the value currently stored in the register as a hex-number.

What I would like to do is write a python-script that does exactly what I'm doing manually right now, i.e. read the Serial and save the incoming data from the register to an array. I have tried

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 115200, stopbits=2)
data = ser.readline(1000)
print(data)
```

The baud rate and stopbits are what I'm using in CuteCom as well, where it works perfectly.

When I run this, the cursor jumps a line down and just sits there, which means the program is running, however, it never terminates and it does not show me any data. I'm wondering whether I'm doing this right. In CuteCom I had to specifically tell it to read from the register at this certain address, whereas here my understanding is that I tell it to output anything that comes into the port. Why would there be anything coming in if I never give an order to read from the register though? How can I get the processor to read the register and output the content to the port in Python? Let me know if I'm not making sense, I'm not vastly experienced with this :)